# How to set the order of the elements and add comments in the development of web services using bottom-up approach?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, soapui

I'm new in web services. I use bottom-up approach during the development. After WS created  I test it using SOUP UI. Sometimes I create documentation (wsdl-report) using the same tool. Unfortunately when I receive the response from web service the elements are returned in strange order. 
Question: 
(1) how using bottom-up approach specify the order of elements in the web service output response and
(2) how to add elements description in java code for generating documentation with annotations?
In other words what i need:
1. ordered element in web service response
2. comments in wsdl-reports generated by SOAP UI

Comment: For your order problem look up "sequence". Here is one example: http://oreilly.com/catalog/webservess/chapter/ch06.html

Comment: As I understand there top to botom (from wsdl to classes) method is described.